# This item cannot be deleted because it is still referenced by other pages. SharePoint 2013 Display Template

Tags: 2013, display-template

I am trying to delete a display template's html file.

I tried PowerShell script, tried doing it manually, and also tried SP Designer to delete.

But with all I am getting same error.

```
Error: this item cannot be deleted because it is still referenced by other pages.
```

Any idea why it's happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have the content deployment or cross site publishing enabled?

Comment: is that template is being used in any page?

Comment: No content deployment and no cross site publishing. Its a publishing portal and display templates are used in search.

Comment: so any webpart using it?

Comment: That display template is used in Content By Search Web part. I have more than 1 display template but this error is caused only on one of it.

Comment: so may be this one is being used on any webpart that's why you getting this error.check the search webpart, if this template is being used then change to different one then again try to delete it.

Comment: So what should I do? Remove reference from webpart?

Comment: yes, because this template is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research and investigation, I noticed that Display templates got deployed incorrectly.

I have a wsp package which is deployed and activated using PowerShell script.

The wsp solution contained display templates, one of the Display template's JavaScript file was converted with a name which was already in use by other.

So when we deployed for the first time there was no error, but for the second time (which included a script to delete display template) failed and error was thrown.

Finding the newly deployed display templates from design manager, and removing it from there proved a lucky shot. And the error was solved.

I hope this information is helpful

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, Looks Like you display template is being used in one of the search web part.

- Please check the properties of the Search Web part on all pages. if this template is being used. Please change it to different template.
- After changing try to delete it now.
- If you still getting the error please share the uls for that time period when you get the error.

Comment: Hi Waqas, 
Thanks for your help. Your answer was very helpful in getting to the root cause of the error, I have posted what was wrong. I hope its helpful.